# Expect script fails on foreach loop

Tags: loops, ssh, foreach, expect

I have an expect script that cycles through a file with a list of hosts, ssh's into each one, sudo's to root, and runs id. The problem is it never returns to the source servers shell. It attempts to run from the host it has ssh'd into, thus messing up the logic.

```
set file [open "hosts.test"]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $file] "\n"]
close $file

foreach host $hosts {
    puts $host
    spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  [lindex $argv 0]@$host
    expect "Password: "
    send "[lindex $argv 1]\r"
    expect -re "(>|#) "
    send "sudo su -\r"
    expect "Enter YOUR password: "
    send "[lindex $argv 1]\r"
    expect -re "(>|#) "
    send "id\r"
    expect -re "(>|#) "
    send "exit\r"
    expect -re "(>|#) "
    send "logout\r"
    close $spawn_id
 }
```

Here is the error:

```
send: sending "logout\r" to { exp4 }
server.blah.com
spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {21856}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Password: "? no
Password:
expect: does "Password: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Password: "
send: sending "passwordhere\r" to { exp5 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(>|#) ' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "(>|#) "? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no


expect: does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "(>|#) "? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
Password:
expect: does "\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "(>|#) "? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
expect: timed out
send: sending "sudo su -\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does "\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Enter YOUR password: "? no


expect: does "\r\nPassword: \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Enter YOUR password: "? no
Password:
expect: does "\r\nPassword: \r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Enter YOUR password: "? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "passwordhere\r" to { exp5 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(>|#) ' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "\r\nPassword: \r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "(>|#) "? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no


expect: does "\r\nPassword: \r\nPassword: \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "(>|#) "? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nPassword: \r\nPassword: \r\n"
send: sending "id\r" to { exp5 send: spawn id exp5 not open
while executing
"send "id\r""
("foreach" body line 11)
invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
    puts $host
    spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  [lindex $argv 0]@$host
    expect "Password: "
    send "[lindex $argv 1]\r"
    e..."
(file "./bootstrap.exp" line 19)
```

Comment: Looks like you're entering the wrong login password.

Comment: I changed the cleartext pw here. That's not the problem

Comment: The problem is that it never exits back to the source server. It trys to spawn again from the first server it logs into, so it never gets back to the original shell, which it expects to in the script. So it throws the logic off.

Comment: Looking at the debug output I see the same Password: prompt repeated. I conclude that the password is not being sent correctly

Comment: Do you see all the timeout messages?

Comment: So its sending the password right for the first host, and then not for the second host? I don't understand how that's possible. It successfully logs into the first host.

Comment: ...and I did verify access to the test servers in question. Kerberos is in play, so everything is good

Comment: All the information I have is in the debug output. You match the Password: pattern, but none of the other -- they all time out until the ssh session is closed.

Comment: glenn, you were absolutely right. Apparently the problem server had been marked for decomm the day after I started testing, and no one sent me the memo. Thank you sir, and my mistake. Its cycling through servers correctly... onto the next piece.